# Is there any way we can connect google colab display to our system using Xlib Python?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, xlib

I wanted to use Xlib library (Python Module) [ [Documentation](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/), [Pypi Page](https://pypi.org/project/python-xlib/) ] to connect the display of google colab to my local machine. Is there any way we can do that by creating a client script in python.

I want to know how can we configure the client system to accept the connection.

If you know any good references please do provide them.

Thanks for answering in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you looking at grabbing the screen from Colab Notebook and then display it in your local machine? Or are you looking to run your Colab notebook locally?

Comment: Grab the screen or Any thing that needs a display from Colab Notebook and then display it in your local machine. Thanks for taking time to comment. I really appreciate it.